# Removing a div with child divs

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if i remove a div which had div's inside of it using :

```
var div = document.getElementById('main');
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

Will this also remove all the Divs that are inside of it ? Or will i have to clear `innerHTML` first?

Comment: It will remove all the child nodes. Is it not same as clearing innerHTML?

Comment: It probably took longer to post this question than a simple test would have taken.

Comment: Well now people who may google/search for such a question have the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove an element from the DOM, you remove its children as well.